How to make Vue only change browser link but not refresh all browser
I used to run Vue "inside" Laravel project by writing .js, .vue files in resources/js folder of a Laravel project.
When I run website, browser (Chrome) did not refresh when clicking any link.
But when I split that project into Laravel and Vue seperately (with same packages) as follow:
project
|___backend
|___frontend

The browser refresh every time I click any link.

Additionally, website's performance is down. It takes more time to load.

And what do you want to achive? No browser reload is most of the time a good sign while using vuejs

First you have to install vue router plugin Vue Router
npm install vue-router

bind vue-router with vue like this
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

After that declare route
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')'

then use
<router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>

instead of
<a href="/foo">Go to Foo</a>

